# Reimporting multiple pom.xml files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I checkout my maven project I receive multiple compilation errors that imports are not found :

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import com.custom.*;
```

returns :

```
Cannot resolve symbol Optional

Cannot resolve symbol Stream

Cannot resolve symbol custom
```

`custom` is a custom maven project that is deployed on Nexus.

My project contain maven modules, in order to fix the above errors I "reimport" the pom.xml for each project :

[image]

There are approx 100 sub modules this process is required for and so is extremely time consuming when building. How to re-import each pom.xml individually ?

I could select each pom.xml individually and "reimport" but this is also time consuming.

I've also tried reimporting the parent pom but this does not reimport the sub-modules.

I'm using `Intellij` IDE.

Comment: If you provide maven-compiler-plugin in parent pom.xml file, it should work for all sub modules.

Comment: The button 'Reimport All Maven projects' in Maven tool window synchronizes **All** Maven projects at once. But if these are maven module from [multi module Maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) you need to import onlth the main pom.xml.